# Xcode: Get update of framework project in app project dynamically from framework project in same workspace

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks, xcode-workspace

I have a scenario where I have a workspace file in which I have one Cocoa touch framework and one iOS application. 
iOS application uses this framework.

I have successfully created framework universal library with help of aggregate target in framework project.

I am successfully able to add the framework (Above mentioned with help of aggregate that runs on simulator, device and archive) in my iOS application project. (I embedded the framework file in my application project).

Now, whenever I do any change in my framework project I build the framework project with aggregate target, this step successfully updates my application project and framework library used in it.

**I don't want this step of building framework project every time I do change in it to get changes reflected in application project with framework.
How can I automate the my iOS application project to automatically fetch changes whenever I am running the iOS application?**

Comment: Just change the *Scheme* to build the framework and not the app?

Comment: But this won't run the app. I want to get updated framework when I run the app.

Comment: OK, then you have no choice to do what you're doing.  Embedding the framework into the app is the only way the app can access the framework, so there is nothing else you can do.

Comment: Do I have any other option of referring to framework (other than embedding framework), where my desired result can be achieved?

Comment: No, I don't see how.  Make more changes before rebuilding, if you are frustrated with development cycle time.

Comment: Hmm, Ok. Doesn't my app build the referenced framework when I am making/compiling the my app project? I am trying to see if something can be picked at that point. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to Edit Schemes and select build for targets and add you universal target.

And move your universal target above your app target.